# Fazer div aparecer ao clicar com botão direito do mouse

Tags: jquery, html, css

Galera eu uso a função (hover) para fazer uma DIV aparecer, queria saber se tem como eu fazer ele aparecer ao clicar com o botão direito. Ou seja, uma DIV filho aparecer quando eu clicar em uma DIV pai com botão direito.

Segue um exemplo que estou tentando aqui.

```css
.pagina {
    width: 200px;
   margin-left: 119px;
}

#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu a {
    line-height: 40px;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #484848;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: -119px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    display: block;
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
    background: #1E90FF;
}
```

```html
<div class='pagina'>

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>x</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
                <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>

<div class='pagina'>

<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'>x</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
                <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events - Recomendo que dê uma olhada

Comment: Explique melhor qual será a div pai e qual será a filho.

Comment: Bom no exemplo acima eu queria que o menu abrace ao clicar com o botão direito. A questão da DIV pai e da DIV filho seria assim. Tenho uma DIV id=pai, ao clicar com o botão direito sobre ela uma DIV id=filho aparece. Entendeu?

Comment: @HugoBorges eu postei uma resposta abaixo, basta adaptar a sua necessidade. Só entendendo melhor a pergunta, o pai seu são as `li` que tem o a href?

Comment: sim isso mesmo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nessa resposta do [*SO-EN*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706655/bind-event-to-right-mouse-click) tem o que deseja. Use o evento `mousedown` e verifique se foi o botão direito que foi acionado através do código  `if(e.button == 2)` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0d3ketxk/).

Aproveitando eu trocaria o `display:none` por [hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden), novo atributo do *HTML5*.

Com base nos seus comentários adaptei o seu código para funcionar como necessita:

```js
document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

  $('li').mousedown(function(e){ 
    if(e.button == 2) { 
      $(this).find('ul').show();
    } 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='cssmenu'>
   <ul>
      <li class='has-sub'>
         <a href='#'>x</a>
         <ul hidden>
            <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
            <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class='pagina'>
   <div id='cssmenu'>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'>
            <a href='#'>x</a>
            <ul hidden>
               <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
               <li><a class='onclick' onclick='document.location="google.com.br";}'><b>link1</b></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok muito bom, porém ao invés de enviar um alert como faço para aparecer outra div?

Comment: @HugoBorges Segue um exemplo da resposta do Marconi com o que deseja. https://jsfiddle.net/0d3ketxk/1/

Comment: muito bom, so tenho mais uma dúvida, é possível fazer a div filha aparecer debaixo do cursor do mouse? eu seja capturar a posição só mouse e colocar ela?

Comment: muto bom, quero saber se e possível fazer o menu fechar ao clicar em outro lugar?

Comment: não deu certo, edita sua resposta por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Bom sei que provavelmente vocês já conseguiram resolver o problema, mais respondendo melhor as perguntas dos colegas aí que ainda devem ter dúvidas, segue abaixo uma explicação de como fazer um menu alternativo personalizado.

**No html** coloque nos elementos tr, div ou ul os seguintes atributos data-toogle="menu" e data-menu="div.menu" onde div.menu é o nome do elemento que será mostrado ao clicar com auxiliar do mouse sobre a tr, div ou ul.

```
<table><tr id="1" data-toggle="openmenu" data-menu="div.teste"><td>...</td></tr></table>
```

E o menu a ser exibido faça dessa forma o nosso div.teste:

```
<div class="teste" style="background: red; color:#FFF;">construa seu menu aqui</div>
```

**No javascript usando o jquery**:

```
//desabilita o botão secundário do mouse
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});

//ativa o menu alternativo para o aplicativo
$('[data-toggle="openmenu"]').mousedown(function(e){
    var el = $(this), menu = el.attr("data-menu"), H = el.height(), posX = e.pageX, posY = e.pageY;
    if( e.button == 2 ) {
        $(menu).css({"position":"absolute", "top":posY-(H+H/2),"left":posX,"display":'',"z-index":"9999"});
        //alert("X "+posX+" Y "+posY+" H "+H);
    }
    //menu é ocultado em segundos ou pode ser chamado quando selecionar uma das opções do menu.
    setTimeout(function(){
        menuhide(menu)
    },10000);
});
menuhide = function (menu) {
    $(menu).css("display","none");
};
```